# What is the Ruby 1.8.7 way of serializing Time without losing precision?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby 2.0 / 1.9.3

```
t = Time.now
t == Time.at(t.to_r)
# => true
```

Clearly:

```
t = Time.now
t == Time.at(t.to_i)
# => false
```

is not going to cut it.

What is the Ruby 1.8.7 way of serializing `Time` short of using `Marshal`, without losing precision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `Time.to_r` wasn't available in 1.8.7, `Time.to_f` was:

```
t = Time.now
t == Time.at(t.to_f)
# => true
```

**Update:** Since it turns out you want to do it the same way in 1.8.7 and 2.0 / 1.9.3, I'll point out that `to_f` is still almost certainly the best choice.  While

```
t == Time.at(t.to_f)
```

now returns `false`, that's only because your Time object in 1.9.3 / 2.0 has even higher precision than a float.

```
t.to_f == Time.at(t.to_f).to_f
# => true

t - Time.at(t.to_f)
# => 8.09310302734375e-08
```

Those are small fractions of a microsecond being lost in conversion to float.

Comment: trouble is time.to_f works in 1.8.7 but does not work correctly in 1.9.3 so you don't have a consistent serialization format

Comment: @SamSaffron First, your question didn't make it at all clear that you wanted something that worked across 1.8.7 - 2.0.0; you just asked for the 1.8.7 way.  You should clarify that.  Second, it does *work*, in that it gives you sub-microsecond precision, which is almost certainly good enough.

Comment: yeah to_f should cut it, just need to make sure other area of the code are aware of it, turns out sprockets already has a bunch of to_i hiding in various spots that may simplify things anyway ... for context https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/pull/428